# Unresolved Host Exception in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, unknown-host

I'm trying to call a servlet deployed on App Engine by passing JSON parameters. Below is the code:

```
    public static String doPost(String url, String jsonData)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 0); // Timeout

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity s = new StringEntity(jsonData);
    s.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
    HttpEntity entity = s;
    request.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    if (resEntity != null) {
        // Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        String responseData = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
        return responseData;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am passing the url as:
http://abcd.appspot.com/

But when code is getting executed in ***emulator*** i am getting "java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved" error. But while executing the same code in ***Android 2.2.1 device*** all things are working fine. But not able to execute the code in any of the ***emulator*** i tried with all versions.

Stacktrace:

```
W/System.err(  987): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: aamjantaatest.appspot.com:80
W/System.err(  987):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1002) W/System.err(  987):   at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117) 
W/System.err(  987):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:129) 
W/System.err(  987):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164) 
W/System.err(  987):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119) 
W/System.err(  987):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
W/System.err(  987):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555) 
W/System.err(  987):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487) 
W/System.err(  987):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465) 
W/System.err(  987):    at com.aamjantaa.android.service.Request.doPost(Request.java:62) 
W/System.err(  987):    at com.aamjantaa.android.intent.StoreListView$StoreListAsynTask.doInBackground(StoreListView.java:170) 
W/System.err(  987):    at com.aamjantaa.android.intent.StoreListView$StoreListAsynTask.doInBackground(StoreListView.java:1) 
W/System.err(  987):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185) 
W/System.err(  987):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:256) 
W/System.err(  987):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:122) 
W/System.err( 987):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648) 
W/System.err(  987):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673) 
W/System.err(  987):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1058)
```

Comment: I have setted all required permission also. i.e., <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 2):

It may be your emulator not connected to internet.Check whether your emulator able to connect to internet or not by launching browser,if not restart emulator.

Comment: Yes i tried to connect with browser and all is working well. The same site is getting open in my browser of emulator. I had restarted it so many times. But when i launch my application i am getting the issue in accessing internet from my application in emulator.

Comment: please check above i had provided the logcat with question only.

Answer (score 0):

the above URL http://abcd.appspot.com/ did not open in browser,I have checked it[image],please check it once again